# Why is God's Judgment only Heaven or Hell?

Tags: heaven, hell, judgment

I know very little of the Christian Faith or of any other faith for that matter, but this question struck me as relevant maybe not just to Christianity but also to all faiths as a whole.

Penal systems on the Earth are there to create order in society and breaking the laws under a particular system have "degrees of penalty" such as a bank robber would be given 10 years in prison whereas an adolescent who stole from a gumball machine outside the local store would only be given a slap on the wrist and told not to do it again.

In both these cases the crime was theft but they are not judged equally.

So why is God's judgment of man so extreme: either man gets eternal bliss or eternal pain?

Why does even the *slightest* transgression of God's law is punished the same as a *greater* transgression?

Comment: It is not true (In Christianity) that 'the slightest transgression of God's law' is punished the same as a 'greater' transgression'. The judgment that results in an eternal destiny (heaven or hell) is based on _the entirety of a person's lifetime upon earth_. This is clear throughout the Christian bible.

Comment: some Christian  denominations believe in a more complicated/thorough life after death, than just heaven/hell

Comment: You're thinking in terms of punishment and legal penalties. OK, and there's something to that, but Jesus and St. Paul speak of becoming a new creature, or being fig trees not bramble bushes, that is, it's a change of nature.

Comment: @NigelJ Will heaven only be populated by people that have repented their sins or will some of that population have done no sin throughout their life?

Comment: The words of Jesus and of Paul convey regeneration, a begetting, a 're-birth', a matter of eternal life, a matter of the indwelling Spirit. It is not a 'change of nature'. We are still human. It is a 'new creation' under a different Headship. But one's identity is the same (despite claims I hear). I have never met anyone and have never read of anyone and have never heard of anyone, who claimed to be without sin and who could stand up to analysis in that regard. 'All have sinned and come short (failing miserably) of the glory of God' saith the scripture.

Answer (score 2):

One either fulfils God's purpose (in one's own humanity) or one does not. The consequences are unavoidable. Failure to fulfil the purpose of God in creating humanity is an absolute. So is the fulfilment of that purpose, an absolute.

The creation around us is made for God's purposes and God's purposes are in humanity, to 'bring many sons to glory'.

And the creation around us is temporary ; it is a means to an end and once that end is fulfilled (in redemption) the whole universe will be changed. 'Even the heavens are not clean in his sight' and 'the stars shall fall to the earth'.

Once the heavens and the earth are put away (in order that new may be fashioned as an environment for the redeemed) then, where shall the rejectors of redemption be placed after their (inevitable) resurrection ?

Where else can they go but to the lake of fire which is the result of the putting away of the old creation ?

Heaven and hell (*gehenna*, the lake of fire) are absolutes.

*Because the nature and the righteousness of God are absolutes.*

Answer (score 2):

God's judgement is only ever righteous judgment. ***It is the*** **consequences** ***of God's judgment that you ask about***, but until the fact that God is utterly righteous in all his ways (including in his judgments) is understood, there can be no understanding of the consequences of his judgment.

God will "judge the world in righteousness" (Acts 17:3 & Psalm 9:8). Christians know that "in the gospel is the righteousness of God revealed... the righteousness of God without the law is [shown] ...even the righteousness of God which is by faith of Jesus Christ... faith in his blood to declare God's righteousness" (Romans 1:17, 3:21-22 & 25).

This is why ***Christianity is unique in its presentation of God's righteous judgment***. Until people see how God publicly displayed his righteous judgment of sin by his wrath being poured out on his sinless Son, so that we could be cleansed from our sin, there can be no understanding of the righteous outcome of God's individual judgments on people. Whether they are granted unmerited bliss in heaven for eternity in God's holy presence, or kept outside of his presence (which will be hell), either way, that will be the right outcome.

None of that is relevant to other world faiths, because they always look at the matter from the human standpoint - not God's. They weigh matters as if they were the Judge and the jury, and declare what they think God ought to do. That is why what God has declared he will do shocks billions of people. Some even take offense at God - the very idea that he would even allow a place like hell to exist horrifies them.

The idea of heaven or hell as the only two possible eternal outcomes strikes them as extreme (unbalanced, in other words) because if they had a say in the matter, there should be interim 'stages' and second (or third or more) chances to work one's way up to heaven, eventually. "If at first you don't succeed, try, try, try again" seems to be the human idea. But that idea is based on the sinful human notion that sin isn't really *that* bad, well, not most sin anyway. Surely God could wink at *some* sin?

Well, reflection upon what the Son of God had to endure so that God could deal righteously with sin, in one fell swoop of his sword of judgment on the sinless One, should disabuse us of that idea. It should get us down on our knees in horror at sin, at our own total unworthiness to be forgiven, to cling to the foot of the now empty cross and plead in the name of the only Mediator God has appointed to bring sinners to God - Jesus Christ.

Once we admit the truth that "All have sinned and fallen short of the glory of God" (Romans 3:23) and that "in my flesh dwelleth no good thing" (Romans 7:18) - applying that personally - then we will begin to understand why the consequences of God's righteous judgment can only have two permanent outcomes.

**Conclusion:**  Only once we understand the basis of God's judgment on humanity can we see why there are only those two eternal outcomes. Once we see the consistency of God's judgments and how that will apply to the final judgment of all the living, and all the resurrected dead, will we agree with the cry of his people in the revelation of that Day of Judgment:

> "Alleluia; Salvation, and glory, and honour, and power unto the Lord
> our God. For true and righteous are his judgments: for he hath judged
> the great whore, which did corrupt the earth with her fornication, and
> hath avenged the blood of his servants at her hand. And again they
> said, Alleluia. And her smoke rose up for ever and ever." Revelation
> 19:1-3 & 11 A.V.

Answer (score 1):

**Two Considerations** God's Heaven is a place of perfection. To allow people there who have any hint of a sin would contaminate the whole characteristic of that pristine place. Think of a woman going down the aisle in a wedding ceremony with a white dress. Now consider that the woman ate a hot dog just before the ceremony, and spilled the smallest drop of catsup on her dress!

What do you think the ladies in the pews would talk about?  The lovely dress...or the stain they see on the dress? So it is with Heaven. A person allowed in with a little sin, would stand out tremendously.

God does not "grade on the curve." Nothing short of perfection is the attribute of Divinity and spiritual reality. This is why **imputed righteousness** is so important. The righteousness of Christ is freely given to us to make up for all our "short-comings." (sinfulness) Without this graceful gift no human could make it to heaven!

**Also Consider** There is an available Redemption for the sinner, whether he has committed a small crime, or large serial act. It was a price paid by no less than the Son of God...and it is readily available freely to all. The most horrific death on the Cross was experienced by Christ because He loved humanity.

Any who turn their back on this gesture of forgiveness is highly offensive to Heaven. For any person not to avail himself of this **substitutionary punishment** deserves no pity.  Whether a murderer or pick-pocket. Whether the punishment were 5 years or eternity, the punishment was subject to cancellation totally!!! The **rap sheet** could have been wiped clean by the offer of mercy and grace of God. A forgiven sinner cannot be called an **ex-con** because there is no existing record! He can only be called a **convert**. To turn down this amazing offer given by the Majesty of the Universe is most offensive. Inexcusable.

For God to down play the death of His Son and say, "Okay, I'll let you get away with five years; you don't have to repent totally. It was just a little sin, after all," would be a mockery of justice...as well as a mockery of Jesus who went through all the suffering. **Justice tempered by Mercy** demands **all or nothing at all**.  **Heaven or Hell**

Comment: @ Matthew - Most grateful thank you for your observation!  Blessings on your Bible studies.

Answer (score 0):

Salvation is **binary**, there is no neutral destination. It's either you heard, believed and changed or you heard and rejected the truth which makes you guilty  of a greater sin than those who never heard.

**why can't your computer understand anything else than a 0 and 1?**

Comment: Computers (once given the proper components) can understand a situation of zero, or one, or both, or anywhere in between. I don't think that is a good argument.

Comment: To be more precise, I should say 'computers can process' rather than 'understand'. 'Understanding' pertains only to the living.

Comment: @NigelJ, you may be right. Computers are just circuits that do what is expected of them

Answer (score 0):

The Bible teaches that the rewards for the righteous are:

- Identical for all believers (Parable of the Laborers in the Vineyard, Matthew 20:1-16)
- Differ in magnitude between believers (Rewards in Matthew 10:40-42, Parablwe of the Talents in Matthew 25:14-30, and 1 Corinthians 3:10-15, which ends by saying "*If anyone's work is burned up, he will suffer loss, though he himself will be saved, but only as through fire.*")

The Bible also teaches that all in Hell suffer:

- an equal punishment
- different degrees of punishment, according to their crimes (Revelation 20:11-15, the White Throne judgment)

The rewards and punishments are all eternal, so equal. They are all proportional to something related to how we lived, so are unequal.

When it comes down to it, the greatest treasure is Jesus Christ:

> For I want you to know how great a struggle I have for you and for
> those at Laodicea and for all who have not seen me face to face, 2
> that their hearts may be encouraged, being knit together in love, to
> reach all the riches of full assurance of understanding and the
> knowledge of God's mystery, which is Christ, 3 in whom are hidden **all
> the treasures of wisdom and knowledge**. (Colossians 2:1-3)

You either have Jesus (and he you) - or you don't.

Comment: So God is a dialetheist. That there are true contradictions?

Comment: The degree of difference will be the degree of capacity. It will  not be a matter of 'proportion'. These states are absolute, for all participants. But some have more capacity (the capability of experiencing the state) than others.

Answer (score 0):

> So why is God's judgment of man so extreme: either man gets eternal bliss or eternal pain?

First off, we should be clear that not all Christians believe "eternal pain" is the consequence of rejecting Christ. Many believe in [annihilationism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annihilationism), or the idea that some or all unbelievers will cease to exist, perhaps after a period of punishment commensurate to their sins.

Second, as many noted, there are Scriptures that suggest the rewards or consequences are not all equal. For further reading and Scriptural citations, see e.g. [here](https://www.thegospelcoalition.org/essay/degrees-punishment-hell/), [here](https://www.gotquestions.org/levels-hell.html) or [here](https://carm.org/about-sin/are-there-different-degrees-of-punishment-in-hell/).

More importantly, however, it is necessary to understand the *actual* nature of the dichotomy. What's at stake isn't "punishment or bliss", it's whether one spends eternity *with* God, or *without* God. Framed this way, it should be more obvious that there *is* a dichotomy; there is no such thing as an eternity in which you get to visit God but only on Fridays. [Ray's answer](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/99984/53502) already did a decent job of explaining how that would be rather silly. A person may be punished for specific sins, but ultimately, "hell" is about being separated from God.

Moreover, Salvation is a *free gift*. Those that don't spend eternity with God are those that don't *want* to spend eternity with God. A popular saying says that 'there are only two kinds of people; those who say to God "Thy Will be done", and those to whom God says "thy will be done"'. There is some thought that it is actually *more merciful* for God to allow those who are not Saved to go their own way rather than "forcing" them to abide in an eternity they rejected.

In any case, it is necessary of course to also understand that **no one** is sinless. Moreover, we are so calloused to Sin that we are blind to the reality of just how horrible it is. Jesus said (more than once!) 'it is better for a man to enter the Kingdom blind and maimed than to be thrown into the Fire'... which does *not* mean we ought to mutilate ourselves, but rather that the most horrible temporal sufferings we can imagine would be preferable to having even the slightest taint of sin. All other things being equal, **all** people would be subject to Judgment and Condemnation. Thanks be to God that He gives us a way out!

Thus, there are several issues with the perception that God's Judgment is "unfair", "unjust", or "excessively binary".

- The nature of eternity is necessarily binary; you are either entirely with God, or you are entirely without God. The "half and half" state is limited to *this* life.
- Even so, there *are* degrees of both reward and punishment. Moreover, not all Christians believe punishment *lasts* "forever".
- Finally, what's "unfair" is that *anyone* is Saved.

Answer (score -1):

> Why is Gods Judgement **only Heaven or Hell**?
>
> So why is gods judgement of man so extreme either man gets eternal bliss or eternal pain?
>
> Why does even the 'slightest' transgression of gods law punished **the same** as a 'greater' transgression?

Great question!

**It isn't, and it doesn't.**

Take this recent quotation from President Dallin H. Oaks, first counselor in the First Presidency of the Church of Jesus Christ of Latter-day Saints:

> From modern revelation we know that the ultimate destiny of all who live on the earth **is not the inadequate idea of heaven for the righteous and the eternal sufferings of hell for the rest**. God’s loving plan for His children includes this reality taught by our Savior, Jesus Christ: “In my Father’s house are **many** mansions.”
>
> The revealed doctrine of the restored Church of Jesus Christ of Latter-day Saints teaches that all the children of God—with exceptions too limited to consider here—will ultimately inherit one of three **kingdoms of glory**, even the least of which “surpasses all understanding.” After a period in which the disobedient suffer for their sins, which suffering prepares them for what is to follow, all will be resurrected and proceed to the Final Judgment of the Lord Jesus Christ. There, our loving Savior, who, we are taught, “glorifies the Father, and saves all the works of his hands,” will send all the children of God to one of these kingdoms of glory *according to the desires manifested through their choice*s.

These kingdoms of glory are also referred to as **degrees** of glory and they correspond precisely to different degrees of obedience and fidelity to God's laws by people here on Earth. This is more thoroughly explained [here in an earlier revelation](https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/scriptures/dc-testament/dc/76?lang=eng) given to Joseph Smith.

There are more than hints of the reality of God's precise justice and eternal kingdoms, including different heavens, in the Bible:

> There are also celestial bodies, and bodies terrestrial: but the glory of the celestial is one, and the glory of the terrestrial is another.
>
> There is one glory of the sun, and another glory of the moon, and another glory of the stars: for one star differeth from another star in glory.
>
> So also is the resurrection of the dead.
> ([1 Corinthians 15:40-42](https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/scriptures/nt/1-cor/15?lang=eng&id=40#p40))

The notion that the thief on the cross next to Jesus would inherit paradise or the same eternal destiny as Jesus irrespective of his sins or repentance is based on a [mistranslation of a single word](https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/manual/gospel-topics/paradise?lang=eng).

The punishment should fit the crime, and God is the originator of this idea, because He is the paragon of justice.

Salvation, perfection and exaltation are not a binary. There are more things than one to be saved from, and [the commandments of God](https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/scriptures/ot/ex/20?lang=eng) and the laws taught by the Savior show us what we must do to obtain the fullness of salvation and exaltation.